How to override Missing $ inserted while writing MATLAB program?
I hope you are having a great time writing your documents using your favorite TeX distribution.
I am learning LaTeX on the Overleaf platform for preparing the reports of my assignment. I am trying to insert a MATLAB code using the matlab-prettifier package. However there is one particular section of the MATLAB code which needs $...$ as it is treating it in the inline Math mode which is as follows:

for which the error is :

In MATLAB this is used for providing subscript. I don't want to enclose it in $...$ as it would violate the MATLAB's format. Please suggest a way to compile the LaTeX code successfully without having to make any modifications to the MATLAB code.
I have just used the typical\lstinputlisting method to include the MATLAB code :

I think this is the most obvious way to do it. Please tell how to compile the LaTeX without disturbing the MATLAB formatting.
Thanks!

You're not showing any code so how are others suppose to help?

Have you read section 7.2 of the matlab-prettifier user manual?

Try with D_0 or should be 0 subscript?

Is something stopping from replacing D_0 with D0?

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment. Please add it as a code block and not as image.

Please don't post images of code, no one wants to retype your code in order to test it. Provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as samcarter asks for.
